# JMS messages thread safety for acknowledge-only purposes using RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, concurrency, jms, rdd, distributed-system

I understand JMS Sessions are not thread-safe. However, if I attempt to acknowledge Message objects which are "stored" on Spark RDD's, is the session actually being accessed concurrently? How is routing made to acknowledge each message(s) (or a batch of them) session?
If that is indeed dangerous, any ideas on how could I safely consume JMS messages from Spark and acknowledge them after some validations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: This is actually a conceptual/theoretical question. A code example would be a one-liner to reflect not much. However, here it is:
messages.forEachRDD(_.foreach(_.acknowledge()))

Answer (score 0):

JMS is just an API so it really depends on the client implementation you are using. However, I would say that most implementations would internally use the session which was used to consume the message originally to acknowledge the message since the session would be the simplest way to send the acknowledgement back to the JMS server where the message came from. Therefore, it would be dangerous to acknowledge messages from the same session concurrently.

I'm not familiar with Spark so I can't address that part of your question.